# Change the value and text of dropdown

Tags: jquery, html

I want to change option of dropdown through jquery according the value i have. and show the text according that value have
html:-

```
<select id="OfferType">
 <option value="Unspecified" selected="selected">Unspecified</option>
 <option value="FreeOffer">Free Offer</option>
 <option value="LowOffer">Low Offer</option>
 <option value="AddOffer">Add Offer</option>
 <option value="PercentageOffer">Percentage Offer</option>
 <option value="GroupOffer">Group Offer</option>
</select>
```

in jquery

```
if (('filterby' in urlParams) && (urlParams['filterby'] == 'LowOffer')) {
    $("#OfferType").val("LowOffer");
    $('#OfferType option[value=LowOffer]').text('Low Offer');
     submitAjaxOffersSearch();
  }
```

data is sorted according **val("LowOffer")** but in dropdown text not Show **text("Low Offer");**

Comment: Why would you reset the text, if it is already in the option? `$("#OfferType").val("LowOffer");` should be enough.

Comment: even without that the text is not show according val.

Comment: Try this  $("select[id$='OfferType']").val("LowOffer");

Comment: Not sure what the issue here is: http://jsfiddle.net/HZSTR/

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#OfferType').val('LowOffer'); //sets the value
alert($('#OfferType option:selected').text()); //gets the text
```

The selector '#OfferType option:selected' gets the element of id OfferType (#OfferType)
and the options where they are selected (option:selected)

[jquery val()](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http://api.jquery.com/val/&ei=KkZsUcyFJ4WV0AWljIGoDQ&usg=AFQjCNH-GtfNf_4YLXDtVLm7PPh0POeseA&sig2=4tMhpoaHD4w02rBXSt7HQw)

[jquery text()](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAA&url=http://api.jquery.com/text/&ei=AkZsUb3zKKKj0QWJsoDQDQ&usg=AFQjCNH_op1krIyMiANGFM-1-_RiNyug6w&sig2=dS4V_xy7Vci5hYwY79Vi2w)

Comment: Why -1, did I miss something?  That does exactly what was asked?  It sets the dropdown box and then it shows the text.